# Does Sauron wane?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

Apparently [Tolkien's Middle-Earth is in continuous decline](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/283246/what-is-the-mechanism-behind-the-continuous-decline-in-middle-earth) - the greatness of the past is always ebbing away.

Given that, is Sauron also waning? Could he for example [conquer Middle Earth](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/227059/did-sauron-have-the-military-power-to-control-all-middle-earth), then wane to the point where an uprising overthrows him?

Comment: Somewhere in the Silmarillion is a reference to the Gift of Men being something that, as time wears on, even the Powers will envy. This suggests that all the Valar and Maiar (including Sauron) would endure some diminishment over time, if not as quickly as that endured by the Eldar (being *inhernently* bound to Arda).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We have it from Gandalf that, had Sauron conquered in the Third Age, none could foresee it ending until the end of time, including Gandalf the White.

> Concerning this thing, my lords, you now all know enough for the understanding of our plight, and of Sauron's. If he regains it, your valour is vain, and his victory will be swift and complete: so complete that **none can foresee the end of it while this world lasts.**
> (The Lord of the Rings, The Last Battle

Moreover, it's not quite right to say that Middle Earth is in some metaphysical constant decline (well, maybe morally) - that isn't so. Many things were architected so that in some respects, it would *appear* to us so; for example, the Valar, by design, play a lesser role as time goes on, and so do the Elves, ceding the world to Men. Similarly, some works of magic are so great they can only be done once, but this not in turn require the world to be in continual decline. The Trees could only be made once, Feanor could make the Silmarils only once, Morgoth could only make the world his Ring once, and Sauron could make the Ring only once - and this is because they put so much of themselves into the work.

But consider that Feanor himself, who made the greatest works of the Eldar, was not himself of the first Elves! What he did was greater than all the Elves who came before him. (Indeed, according to Tolkien,  many of the first Elves become Avari, who seemingly never did much at all.)

But perhaps a better example, and more pertinent, would be Morgoth. Morgoth *himself* became personally weaker, yes. But that's *because* he poured all his power and will into dominating Middle Earth.

> Melkor 'incarnated' himself (as Morgoth) permanently. He did this so as to control the hroa,2 the 'flesh' or physical matter, of Arda. He attempted to identify himself with it. A vaster, and more perilous, procedure, though of similar sort to the operations of Sauron with the Rings. Thus, outside the Blessed Realm, all 'matter' was likely to have a 'Melkor ingredient',3 and those who had bodies, nourished by the hroa of Arda, had as it were a tendency, small or great, towards Melkor: they were none of them wholly free of him in their incarnate form, and their bodies had an effect upon their spirits.
>
> But in this way Morgoth lost (or exchanged, or transmuted) the greater part of his original 'angelic' powers, of mind and spirit, while gaining a terrible grip upon the physical world. For this reason he had to be fought, mainly by physical force, and enormous material ruin was a probable consequence of any direct combat with him, victorious or otherwise. This is the chief explanation of the constant reluctance of the Valar to come into open battle against Morgoth. Manwe's task and problem was much more difficult than Gandalf's. Sauron's, relatively smaller, power was concentrated; Morgoth's vast power was disseminated. The whole of 'Middle-earth' was Morgoth's Ring, though temporarily his attention was mainly upon the North-west. (HoME, Morgoth's Ring)

Morgoth only *looks* personally weaker because all his power and will is disseminated throughout the whole world, corrupting and warping everything material until the very end of time. Given Morgoth's magical influence on the world, even after his execution and ejection, endures until the end, there's no reason to believe that Sauron, with the Ring, his own externalization of power, would also weaken more than he already did: nearly all of his power was already in the Ring, which is why destroying it killed him. (And why being killed while in physical form always diminishes him: he's "spending" himself in a way that's then destroyed.) As Gandalf continues:

> For he will lose the best part of the strength that was native to him in his beginning, and all that was made or begun with that power will crumble, and he will be maimed for ever, becoming a mere spirit of malice that gnaws itself in the shadows, but cannot again grow or take shape. And so a great evil of this world will be removed. (The Lord of the Rings, The Last Debate)

As a further note, Tolkien adds that the morgoth-element in matter, is in fact the *source* of most evil magic, and it will never "go away" without the destruction of all matter:

> **No such eradication of Morgoth was possible, since this required the complete disintegration of the 'matter' of Arda.** Sauron's power was not (for example) in gold as such, but in a particular form or shape made of a particular portion of total gold. Morgoth's power was disseminated throughout Gold, if nowhere absolute (for he did not create Gold) it was nowhere absent. **(It was this Morgoth-element in matter, indeed, which was a prerequisite for such 'magic' and other evils as Sauron practised with it and upon it.)** (HoME, Morgoth's Ring)

So as long as there is a material world, Sauron can practice magic. And his own power has already been externalized into a (he thought) invincible tool of domination, he doesn't really have much to worry about personally.

Comment: It looks like there is an errant "A vaster, and" in your second quote.

Comment: @ClaraDiazSanchez: Thanks, I could have sworn I fixed that.

Answer (score 5):

He certainly does.

He starts as the greatest servant of Aulë, "god" of invention. Joins Morgoth, loses, and hides in shame. Binds most of his power to The One Ring. Becomes form-locked to an evil warlord after the drowning of Númenor. Loses the Ring and his body again after The Last Alliance. And finally is reduced to a powerless whisper when the Ring is destroyed.

If he had won at any point, he would likely have put more and more of himself into dominating the world and defending against possible Valar invasions over time, gradually weakening until he was basically an empty husk for the Ring to use, much like the ringwraiths.

Comment: Sauron was convinced the Valar had abandoned MIddle Earth, and I don't know about his continual personal weakening. Sauron probably could have ruled ME indefinitely had he conquered in TA. Externalizing his power into the Ring probably helped in this regard.

Comment: @Shamshiel the problem is the universe is predicated on the necessary story of the waning of magic. As in, it's not possible for the story to be Sauron ruling indefinitely. Out-of-Universe Tolkein defined it to be so, and in-Universe the Song of the Ainur did.

Comment: @OrangeDog --- Gandalf didn't see it like that. "If he [Sauron] regains it [the Ring] ... his victory will be swift and complete: so complete that none can foresee the end of it while this world lasts." (The Last Debate.) Perhaps the fact that the good side also 'wanes' would enable Sauron to remain in power indefinitely.

Comment: "I returned, and saw under the sun, that the race is not to the swift, nor the battle to the strong, ...nor yet favor to men of skill; but time and chance happeneth to them all."  *How* he'd fall is can not be foreseen even by the Wise, but sooner or later he'd make a mistake or have an accident (tripping while touring Mt Doom, anyone?) and would be again diminished. Men would die and die and die, but not be diminished. In the end, Sauron is doomed. (But the end may be far off and it's still better to oppose him *now*.)

Comment: @MarkOlson --- Men were already diminished at the time of the War of the Ring. A Numenorean sending force absolutely thumped Sauron's armies at the end of the War of the Elves and Sauron. In the War of the Ring, men just held on, hoping that Frodo could do them a favour. Had Gondor and Rohan been destroyed, men would have been diminished further.

Comment: @Ian Thompson Men were diminished in their civilization, yes. But that's trivial and reversable. The diminishing that Elves and other primarily spiritual beings suffer when they act badly in the material world is a permanent diminishment of their essential being which is unrecoverable (as far as we can tell.) (If Sauron was a Human bad guy who fell, he could reasonably hope that one of his descendants would rise to once again menace the world with everlasting darkness. Your grandkids may hope to be just as evil as you.)

Comment: @MarkOlson --- The life-span of high men had also been reduced by the time of the War of the Ring. According to LotR appendix A (iv) this 'waning' (Tolkien's own word) was due to the slow withdrawing of the gifts of the Numenoreans.

Comment: @Ian Thompson I'm getting a feeling that this discussion is likely to remain unproductive, but I'll post once more: *Some* Men, at the end of the First Age, were given a gift of long life as a reward for what they had done. This "add-on" waned, but the natural span of a normal human life did not. Human potential today in the Seventh Age is no less than it was for all but a few in the Second Age. (And the Numenoreans, for all their gifts, never visited the Moon!)

Comment: @OrangeDog: The universe is not predicated on that, though that's a popular fan opinion. The Valar have a declining role, and the Elves Fade, which has the *effect* of a decline in magic, but that is *not* the same thing as *the world* going endlessly on in the waning of magic *necessarily*. This isn't The Magic Goes Away. The vanishing of magic is a *contingent* effect of other things going on, not an inevitability, and Tolkien would say there is still magic in our time.